# Setting up codeigniter in Dreamweaver CS 5.5

Tags: dreamweaver, codeigniter-2, code-hinting

I am looking for information on how to set up a code igniter project in Dreamweaver CS 5.5 with code hinting like you can for Zend framework.

Comment: I know a lot of people just wouldn't use dreamweaver. but I like some of the functionality. I was wondering if you just point the code hinting to the library like you do with zend

Comment: use codelobster. there is a plugin in it. while coding you can auto select methods and much more is available

Comment: I see you have to pay for the plugin?

Comment: Does anyone have experience with dreamweaver on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to set code igniter up in Dreamweaver CS5.5 by downloading the latest version of code igniter and placing in a folder called php_librarys on the root of my C: drive. I then followed the instructions for site specific code hinting here: [How to set up site specific code hinting](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-dreamweaver-cs5/sitespecific-code-hinting-in-dreamweaver-cs5/). The folder you need to point Dreamweaver to is the libraries folder in the system directory of Code igniter. Just make sure you select recursive and .php as the extension as per the screenshot below:

[image: Site specific hints for codeigniter in dreamweaver]

Comment: In dropdown box, their is only wordpress, joomla and drupal? How to add codeigniter to it?

Answer (score 1):

```
 very simple in dreamwaver to autocomplete any functions in wordpress - codeigniter or even your custom library of code
 steps are as follows:
 1- in dreamwaver open site -> Site Specific Code Hints -> (You can select wordpress-joomla-...) or even any folder like (CI folder) that you mentioned.
 2- do not forget to select (scan this folder,recursive)
 3- it will ask you for custom name just write any one you like "like mynewCI"
 it will create a config file in your selected folder => do not remove it.
 that is all
 the process in detail in this video
 http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-dreamweaver-cs5/using-php-code-hinting-in-dreamweaver-cs5/
 now press ctrl+space and enjoy.
 if this answer was helpful, please vote me up!
 thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this, but with no luck first time. After a while playing into DW to get it working, made pause for a while - and after restart of DW it works.

I used last CI: CodeIgniter-3.0.4.zip

How it was made:

1./ download CI - and extract it into XAMPP htdocs folder into folder code1 (the name You can choose freely) - also: d:\WWW\xampp5615\htdocs\code1\ in My case.

2./ configure Site and Servers in DW to have Live view possible (play with it, sometimes I forget after a while how to do it... :-) )

3./ configure Site-Specific Code Hints in DW - in My case I added the root of site code1 into this menu - see printscreen - and don't forget to define .php extension + recursive + scan

4./ if not working restart DW - it should work now... the index.php renders fully into live view :-) I'm lucky. can learn do some stuff with CI PHP Framework... :-)

Hope it helps...

Printscreen: [CodeIgniter-3.0.4 and Dreamweaver CC 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNXky.jpg)