# Configure CodeIgniter 2.1+ for autocomplete in Dreamweaver or Eclipse with PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter, dreamweaver, eclipse-pdt

I have a small problem in that I want to work with CodeIgniter, but I love to work with Dreamweaver and Eclipse because of their powerful code-hinting features. However, I want to integrate CodeIgniter into my project too, and neither of these two IDEs provide code hinting for CodeIgniter. I have tried to use the steps given in this answer [Setting up codeigniter in Dreamweaver CS 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475598/setting-up-codeigniter-in-dreamweaver-cs-5-5), but even this is not helpful.

I want to know how to configure any of the IDEs to show code hints for CodeIgniter 2.1 or above.

Comment: I used to use Dreamweaver also but have since switched to NetBeans which has all the features I liked about Dreamweaver and more. I never use autocomplete, but here's a link on how to configure autocomplete in NetBeans for CodeIgniter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765908/netbeans-code-completion-for-codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

Very simple in Dreamwaver to autocomplete any functions in WordPress - CodeIgniter or even your custom library of code
steps are as follows:

[image]

[image]

1- in Dreamwaver open site -> Site Specific Code Hints -> (You can select wordpress-joomla-...) or even any folder like (CI folder) that you mentioned.

2- do not forget to select (scan this folder,recursive)

3- it will ask you for custom name just write any one you like "like mynewCI"

it will create a config file in your selected folder => do not remove it.

That is all.

Now press ctrl+space and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

for
 [Eclipse with PDT](http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/autocomplete-eclipse-codeigniter-2)  !the best I use it

---

for 
[Dreamweaver CS5 & CS5.5](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-dreamweaver-cs5/sitespecific-code-hinting-in-dreamweaver-cs5/)