# Codeigniter full code hint with Dreamweaver

Tags: php, codeigniter, code-hinting

I want to know if there's a way to set a full code hint at Dreamweaver with CodeIgniter, I've check this [Setting up codeigniter in Dreamweaver CS 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475598/setting-up-codeigniter-in-dreamweaver-cs-5-5) but I need to know if it can work like this for example:

$this->db->

and at this point that displays all possible functions like query(), insert_id(), affected_rows()...

it is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475598/setting-up-codeigniter-in-dreamweaver-cs-5-5

Comment: mmm... that's the same link I put on my description @Vinod VT